# Slider freezed in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, slider

I have an array of objects which I have filtered in order to get the products I need. The thing is that as a result, I get 10 items instead of 5 (doubled) and the slider isn't working, the images just appear in a column. What may be the issue? Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
import { products } from "../product";



export default function SliderComponent() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
    };
  

    const sliderStyle = {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    };

    const newProducts = products.filter((product) => product.new);


    return (
      <div className="bg-[#000000] slider-container">
        <div className='slide-body pb-[50px]'  style={sliderStyle}>
        <h1>New Arrivals</h1>
        <Slider {...settings}>

          {}
        <div>
        {newProducts.map((product, index) =>{
          if (product.new) {
             return (
        <div key={index} className='shoe-pair'>
          console.log(index)
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
          <h3 className='text-white'>{product.name}</h3>
          <span className='text-white'>${product.price}</span>
        </div>
        
        );
          } else {
            return null
          } 
      })}
      </div>
      </Slider>
      
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: What's the issue? That your slider is not working, or that you get doubled items after filtering? And for the latter that shouldn't be happening with the `filter` method and the way [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters) works is that it must return Boolean, so is `product.new` value evaluating to a Boolean? Can you show the `products` structure example